# Sampling with "unique value" replacement in R

Tags: r, sample

So I've got a question about an easier way to do something.

I'd like to sample from some data with a *special* sort of replacement where the data is replaced by a specific value (rather than any value from the original sample data).

For example, if I want 20 samples from the numbers between 1 and 12 except that I want it to give another number, 0, say, if one of these numbers has already been sampled.

I drafted up this example to show what I mean, using a second sample of logical values (1s and 0s) and then a simple replacement:

```
set.seed(1)

samples <- 20

vector_to_sample <- 1:12 

sampled_vector <- sample(vector_to_sample, size = length(vector_to_sample), replace = FALSE)

logical_vector <- c(rep.int(1, length(vector_to_sample)), rep.int(0, samples-length(vector_to_sample)))

sampled_logical <- sample(logical_vector, size = samples, replace = FALSE)

logical_replacement <- rep.int(0, samples)

replace(sampled_logical, sampled_logical == 1, sampled_vector)

# this should output: 0  4  0  5  6  0  9  2  0  7  10  12  0  0  3  0  1  11  0  8
```

I'm not sure if there's a special word for this kind of replacement, and basically I'm wondering if there's an easier/more efficient way to do this (or an in-built function) that anyone knows of?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 set.seed(1)


 samples <- 20

 vector_to_sample <- 1:12 

 sampled_vector <- sample(vector_to_sample, size = samples, replace = T)

 replace(sampled_vector, duplicated(sampled_vector), 0)
```

Comment: dude, you are on a fire. I am struggling to understand and you are sharp.

Comment: Well i dont know whether it works.. i will look at it when i get to a computer.. using a phone

Comment: it does work. I was running almost the same code while you were typing this -- so i deleted my answer as redundant

Comment: Hm! This seems to work pretty well, except that it throws the following warning `Warning message:
In x[list] <- values :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`
if you have, for example,
`replace(sampled_vector, duplicated(sampled_vector), 1:9)`

Comment: Because whatever you are doing is not in what i write... i do not understand how you would want to replace the values with 1:9 thats not how replace works..